# Need help on mocking Azure CloudBlob

Tags: azure, unit-testing, azure-blob-storage

Here is the function I need to test

```
    [FunctionName("GetImage")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "GetImage/{filename}")] HttpRequest req,
        string filename,
        [Blob("%blobContainerName%/{filename}", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "StorageConnectionAppSetting")] CloudBlobContainer blob,
        ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            CloudBlob img = blob.GetBlobReference(filename);
            Stream test = await img.OpenReadAsync();

            return new FileStreamResult(test, "image/jpeg");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError(ex.StackTrace);
            return new BadRequestResult();
        }
    }
```

And here is the unit test code I have written so far.

```
    public async Task TestOkRequestGetImage()
    {
        _cloudBlobContainer = new Mock<CloudBlobContainer>(new Uri("http://mytest"));

        _cloudBlob = new Mock<CloudBlob>(new Uri("http://mytest.com"));

        Dictionary<string, StringValues> query = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>();

        _cloudBlobContainer.Setup(x => x.GetBlobReference(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(_cloudBlob.Object);

        _cloudBlob.Setup(x => x.OpenReadAsync()).ReturnsAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>());

        var httpReq = HttpRequestSetup(query, "");

        var reqMock = new Mock<HttpRequest>();

        var response = await GetImage.Run(reqMock.Object, "test", _cloudBlobContainer.Object, _log.Object);

        response.Should().BeOfType<FileStreamResult>();
    }
```

Here is the error `TestOkRequestGetImage threw exception:  System.ArgumentException: Invalid blob address 'http://mytest.com/', missing container information (Parameter 'blobAddress')`

Not sure why I cant initialize CloudBob the same way I initialized the CloudBlobContainer. Any tips?

Comment: Blob URL should always be like `https://address/<container-name>/blob-name`. Since you're just using the address portion, you're getting this error I believe.

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri, thank you, and what you said is actually right.